# How to ask the user for input and store the input to then display

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to create a simple interactive Ruby app. I want the user to be able to input the info and then have the program display the info entered.

```
class Player
  def initialize(name, position, team)
    @name = name
    @position = position
    @team = team
  end

  def get_player_info
    puts "Who is your favorite NFL player?"
    name = gets.chomp

    puts "What position does #{name} play?"
    position = gets.chomp

    puts "What team does #{name} play for?"
    team = gets.chomp
  end

  def player_info()
    "#{@name} plays #{@position} for the #{@team}."
  end

end

# Get player info by calling method
get_player_info()

# Display player info
player_info()
```

Right now, I am getting this error:

```
object_oriented.rb:26:in `<main>': undefined method `get_player_info' for main:Objec
t (NoMethodError)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods you are calling are instance methods on the `Player` class, which means you need to create an instance of `Player` in order to call them.

The way you've defined your class, if you want to create a new one (with `Player.new`), you need to supply all three values in order for it to work (`Player.new("Mike", "Center", "Spartans")`). This doesn't jive with you wanting to set variables in instance methods.

To comment on your existing code, I would not do things with `chomp` inside the `Player` class. The `Player` class should only concern itself with the state of the player. If you want to set values I would do all of the prompting outside.

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :name, :position, :team

  def player_info
    "#{name} plays #{position} for #{team}"
  end
end

player = Player.new

puts "Who is your favorite NFL player?"
player.name = gets.chomp

puts "What position does #{player.name} play?"
player.position = gets.chomp

puts "What team does #{player.name} play for?"
player.team = gets.chomp

puts player.player_info
# => "Mike plays Center for Spartans"
```

Comment: When running that code I get object_oriented.rb:14:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `name' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: ah, i forgot to add `player.` to the other method calls. In each prompt, you are trying to access the state of the `player` object, and so you need to call the `name` method on that object. I'll update.

Comment: Okay I see. One other thing is that i must use puts player.player_info to display the method results.